# Joomla - "Class 'JDatabase' not found" on production server

Tags: php, joomla

My site is live, but now I am getting the following error -

```
Fatal error: Class 'JDatabase' not found in /home/xperiumc/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php on line 710
```

Can you tell me why am I getting this error?

Comment: have you recently changed the settings of your server?

Comment: Take a look on this : [Fatal error: Class 'JDatabase' not found](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=625&t=691030). Google is your friend!